# How to update table view when IOS app receives FCM notification

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am new to Swift and Firebase, I had trouble updating my table. My application has a table view on the main page. I expect the application would update the table every time I receive foreground and background FCM notifications.

In the foreground, how would I update the table view, what function or actions should I do to refresh or update the table view when the app receives an FCM notification in the foreground?

In the background, how would I also update the table view? In general, does the app refresh the page automatically or should I also update it by ourselves?

Can someone please help me with this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can expect the push notification to be delivered in the method of your AppDelegate. After which you can post a NSNotificationCenter broadcast.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                 fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
  NotificationCenter.default.post(name: "AppNotification", object: "myObject", userInfo: userInfo)
}
```

which your view controller can observe and refresh your table view.

In your ViewController:

```
func viewDidLoad() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(appnotification), name: "AppNotification", object: nil)
}

@objc func appnotification(notification: Notification) {
    print(notification.userInfo ?? "")
    yourTableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: for foreground updating, do you suggest me update the table every second or is there any smarter way to do it?

Comment: You can update via the NSNotification call back, why do you want to do every second? When the app is foreground and received a notification, the AppDelegate handler gets called which posts the NSNotification broadcast, which is received in your ViewController and you can refresh the table view or do whatever you want.